# Starting musculation at 30 years old, is it good?

Tags: muscle, gym, age

I want to start musculation soon.

I am 30 years old, I am 183cm / 77 kilogrames, the last time I did sport it was maybe 1 year and a half ago.

I wanted to know if to be 30 years old could be more challenging to get muscles ?
Should I eat more ? do more efforts than youngers ? Will my muscles be slowly developed because of my age ?

Thank you.

Comment: The age is not a problem. You will be a bit slower than you wouldve been 10 years ago, but this is a long term effort anyways, a couple of months more don't matter. There are millions of webpages on what you should be doing with your nutrition and how to train, you will find it easy to find them via e.g. google  ;). There is absolutely 0 benefit in asking yourself what you could have done 10 years ago. Progressing is very intuitive here, just do what you can. it might be wise to consult a doctor if you have medical problems of any kind beforehand.

Comment: @Raditz_35 You should add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 8):

It's never too late to start a fitness program that adds muscular size to your physique.  However, as you age, your levels of [testosterone](https://www.healthline.com/health/low-testosterone/testosterone-levels-by-age), the muscle promoting hormone, decline.  That's not to say that you can't add muscular mass after the age of 30.  Many people have.  It will, however, require a conscientious effort and hard work over an extended period of time.  It won't happen over night, assuming you train drug-free.  You'll need to make sure to pay attention to obtaining proper nutrition and rest.  Each of us react differently to training stress, so, you'll need to see what works for you.

Starting a fitness program has other added benefits that include weight control, lower risk of disease, and improved quality of life.  Don't let the desire for muscular mass be the only reason for starting to exercise.  Set small goals. Be consistent, and, train hard.